# How would Google index and rank Two domains that point to the same host

Tags: seo

If I had two domains `A.com` and `B.com`, both of theme point to the same host so :

```
A.com/page.html
```

would display exactly the same result as :

```
B.com/page.html
```

How would Google index and rank both websites ? what is the expected behavior ? Note that there is no redirection applied here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has no problem with indexing your website that has a same host. If you have different content and structures for both your websites, then Google will definitely index your web pages continuously.

But, when it comes for ranking, it has one issue about your IP address. Shared hosting has a C class IP address and it does not provide a unique IP address for each domain. Therefore, it is one of the considerable ranking factor with shared hosting.